# how to create a remote connection between two machines using objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

i am new to Objective C . 
Basically i just wanna know how to write a simple program by which i can send a number from one machine and display it on the other. 
do i need to use sockets or is there any other way..?
i am familiar with java and c++.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way to make DO working on iOS/OSX using a custom framework. Check out this: Distributed Objects on iOS ([1]: http://tkrautter.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/distributed-objects-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have both machines reading from the same database?

Send a value to a PHP script?

Read the database on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

The top answer to this question mentions a Cocoa way of doing this (Distributed Objects): [Objective-C networking - best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567073/objective-c-networking-best-practices)

Comment: Distributed Objects aren’t available on iOS, though.

Comment: True, but the title says "objective-C",

Answer (score 0):

you can use game kit to communicate between two devices via bluetooth or wi fi. check [game kit programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). you can see the code samples [GKTank](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html), [GKTapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html) and [GKRocket](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKRocket/Introduction/Intro.html) which implemet the game kit api