# Multiplayer game communication framework for mac/ios

Tags: macos, multiplayer

I am creating a multiplayer 2D game for Mac and iOS devices. I'll be using cocso2d for graphics/game engine, however I am largely blank on what to use for multiplayer communication. Please note that I cannot use central severs e.g. SmartFox, RedDwarf, etc since I want the players to "host" games for others and be able to play it on their LAN, VPN or my own servers.

Any pointers? I checked [lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) but it's for .NET only and hence not an option for me.

EDIT: the communication has to be real time hence it would probably be over UDP

Comment: may want to post this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567073/objective-c-networking-best-practices

Comment: thank you both. posting to gamedev and looking at the link Travis sent.

Comment: @Travis, the link you mentioned primarily deals with TCP communication, I am updating the question to clear it in case it wasn't already clear that communication in the game has to be real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/multiplayer-game-communication-framework-for-mac-ios) on gamedev.stackexchange.com, I'll be posting my findings there (if any)